# Adding typescript to an existing react App

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add/convert my existing react app (Almost empty) into typescript instead of JS. So based on some tutorials I have added a **tsconfig.json** into my project root with below contents

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
  }
```

Then I installed typescript

```
npm install -g typescript
```

So what I did next is renamed my index.js as index.tsx and app.js and app.tsx and there is simple container component which I renamed to tsx as well.

But when I run the application by **npm start**
its showing below error

[image]

I didnt get what I missed or what I did wrong. Very new to React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install types for the react

```
npm i -D @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It resolved this issue with a minor tweak. So changed it to import * as  React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';